# Crash when opening file in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, crash

I have just installed Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 and it crashes when I try to open a file - also when opening any cpp file through the 'File' menu.

Any ideas? Where is the appropriate forum to ask about this?

Comment: Need more information- Is there a specific error?  OS?

Answer (score 3):

Visual Assist was the culprit - disabled it and now it works fine...

Answer (score 0):

The official forum is here: [Visual Studio 2010 & .NET Framework 4 Beta 2 Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/category/VSPreRelease,netdevelopmentprerelease,visualstudioprerelease,vstsprerelease). You should ask there for better support, perhaps in the [Visual Studio 2010 Install and Setup](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/setupprerelease/threads) forum.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run as administrator the visual studio 2010. Your problem will be resolved.